# how to convert DSA private key to byte[] ?

Tags: dsa, java

Is there any way to convert DSA private key as string or byte[] in java?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about solving a programming problem.

Comment: If you post this on stackoverflow, pretty please make sure you describe your issue in much more detail. Convert to or from? Convert to *what*? What have you tried? What does your private key look like? As it stands, the only sensible answer is "Yes".

Comment: IS the opposite process possible? that is, converting the byte[] to private key using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the `getEncoded()` method of the key.

Related:

- [Save the Signature and the Public Key in Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step4.html)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded()